# Убрать в Head подключаемые стили

Tags: css, wordpress

Всем привет! Есть проблема в `head CMS Wordpress` добавляется портянка стилей на `+200` строк, вопрос, как убрать лишний код `id='hybridextend-style-inline-css'` и просто подключить этот код как отдельный файл, пример:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='hybridextend-style-css' 
  href='https://site.ru/wp-content/themes/magazine-hoot/style.css?ver=1.4.4' 
  type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='hybridextend-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
  .hgrid {
    max-width: 1380px;
  }

  a,
  .widget .view-all a:hover {
    color: #d22254;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #9d193f;
  }

  .accent-typo,
  .cat-label {
    background: #d22254;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .cat-typo-2515 {
    background: #2279d2;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #2279d2;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отключить нужный стиль, нужен хук, и представленный в другом ответе неправильный. 
Вставляете вот такой код

```
function remove_styles () {
    wp_deregister_style ('hybridextend-style-inline'); // без -css
}
add_action ('wp_print_styles','remove_styles',100);
```

И так для каждого стиля отдельно добавляете строчку wp_deregister_style... После отключения подключаете нужный стиль так, как вам удобно. А вообще я бы не советовал такое пихать в functions.php, лучше создайте простенький плагин для этого, легче будет потом применять этот код на других сайтах. Вот пример использования и создания собственного простого плагина https://wpmaster.kz/kak-sozdat-svoj-plagin/

Comment: К сожалению и ваш вариант не сработал!

Comment: Фантастика! На всех своих проектах, оптимизирую этим хуком, ни разу не было, чтобы он не сработал.

Comment: Ну почему фантастика? Если не работает, значит решение не совсем правильное. Вы точно поняли проблему? Мне нужно избавиться от кода , который находится в <style id='hybridextend-style-inline-css' type='text/css'> </script>

Comment: Тема Magazine Hoot

Comment: ААА. То есть добавляется конкретно стили в head? А вам наоборот нужно подключить эти стили в отдельном файле? Если так, то надо было вопрос конкретнее задавать. Портянка, лично для меня и думаю для многих вебмастеров, это куча подключенных файлов стилей в head, а не конкретный стиль.

Comment: В этом случае я советую либо сделать display:none; этому id, либо сделать поиск по файлам шаблона, найти этот скрипт в файлах и удалить его механически. Только после обновления возможно слетит всё. Но не факт. Ну в целом думаю идея понятная.

Comment: Ну я такой вариант тоже рассматривал, но думал есть что-то попроще, придется просто вырезать данный код. Спасибо в любом случае!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в файле `function.php` Вашей темы прописать:
`wp_deregister_style('hybridextend-style-inline-css');`

[wp_deregister_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style)

Answer (score 0):

У меня был тот же вопрос. В общем у меня получилось убрать стили следующим способом.

В файле `function.php` прописала:

```
function wps_deregister_styles() {
  wp_dequeue_style( 'global-styles' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wps_deregister_styles', 100 );
```

И так ниже можно копировать строчку `wp_dequeue_style( 'global-styles' )` и вместо global-styles вставлять свои стили, которые вам надо убрать. При этом в коде написано было `id='global-styles-inline-css'`, то есть `-inline-css` надо было убрать. Перед этим я скопировала все стили и подключила их отдельно.

Надеюсь, кому-то тоже поможет.